# Vue URL Route not updating in state but it does in browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, vue-router, router

I am changing my URL using the following code:

```
    this.$router.push({
      path: this.$route.path + this.initialCategoryPath,
    });
    console.log(this.$route.path);
```

My URL changes to: `www.domain.com/attribute/{{ this.initialCategoryPath content }}`

When I log my route, however, I still only get the /attribute part.

Code to log current route:

```
console.log(this.$route.path)
```

May anyone help me with the question why the URL is not updated in the route state, but it does in the URL?

Comment: Where / when are you logging the path?

Comment: Right under the code where i set the path. I updated the code snippet. This is 1:1 of how it looks in my project

Comment: [`$router.push()`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) is async. You either need to wait for the returned promise to resolve or pass an `onComplete` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$router.push` method pushes a new entry into the [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) stack, so when the user clicks the browser back button they will be taken to the previous URL.

you don't need to add `this.$route.path`. this will add your route to the current path.

you can just simply push like this :

`this.$router.push({ path: this.initialCategoryPath });`

more info :
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html